# Determine when a specific MS Office application .exe was last run

Tags: ms-office

I'm trying to find a way to identify the time that a specific MS Office application .exe (For example, Word) was last run by any person on a particular Windows PC. I'm referring to the locally installed version not a web browser version. The software or script would run locally on the PC.

I can't use the Last Accessed timestamp for the .exe because it can be set by third party software (Anti-virus, backup utility) or it can be turned off.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Can it be done by checking EventViewer or WMI or Graph API? (I can see EventViewer events like "The Software Protection service has completed licensing status check" when I run Word locally but I'm not sure if they're standard for all Word versions).